# PHP always gets a specific value from HTML form

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a HTML form in a wordpress site that sends data to a database. One of the fields asks if a person is male or female using a radio button. How ever even if the persons presses the "Female" radio button they get set to male (Status M)

I've attached my code, the `<?php if( get_theme_mod( 'petition_zip' ) === true ) : ?>` is only a check in my wordpress theme to see if the field should be there. I first tried using only HTML but added some PHP later to try and remidy the problem, it did not so as far as I can tell the PHP attached is close to useless

```
<?php
    $male_status = 'unchecked'; 
    $female_status = 'unchecked'; 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $selected_radio = $_POST['zip'];
        if ($selected_radio == 'M') {

            $male_status = 'checked';

            }
            else if ($selected_radio == 'F') {

            $female_status = 'checked';

            }

    }
?>
            <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'petition_zip' ) === true ) : ?>
            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="radio" id="zip" name="zip" value="M" <?PHP print $male_status; ?>>
                <label for="M">Male</label>

                <input type="radio" id="zip" name="zip" value="F" <?PHP print $female_status; ?>>
                <label for="F">Female</label>   
                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

I'm running queries on the database to confirm the status, everyone that signs up is put to status "M" (Male)

Comment: you have 2 inputs with the same id. Maybe this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Also, you seem to be `print()`ing inside the input elements' opening tags. Not sure what you're aiming for there.

Comment: what does print_r($_POST); give you?

Comment: @Utkanos I followed an online example from W3CSchools 

Sysix thank you for your suggestions! I changed the radio buttons to have different ID's but it did not fix the problem
https://dpaste.de/cR4h

Comment: @Bernhard     print_r($_POST['zip']);  or print_r($_POST); gave me nothing, I assume this is because I'm using wordpress 

It's called "Zip" because I re-used to zip form field for gender instead of having to write an ew one as the theme does not support gender.

Comment: Where is the code that writes the value to the DB? Where is the `form` tag, or is this being submitted with JS?

Comment: @Sysix - the fact that both inputs have the same ID doesn't make any difference to the form submission, it merely stops the labels from functioning properly.

Comment: write "die;" behind print_r($_POST); and you will see something i guess

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) is there a `<form>` ? 2) is there an `<input>` (or `<button>`) with the name *submit* ?

Comment: writing die behind print_r($_POST); did not make anything pring sadly

@CD001 yes there is, you can see the full code at https://dpaste.de/ruyj , the form is almost at the bottom. I did not post all the code as it seems like a hassle for you guys to read it all. 

The submit looks like this `
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $label_button ?></button> `

Comment: Your button needs the name submit, like this `<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">` otherwise `$_POST['submit']` won't exist - or you could just check `if(!empty($_POST))` instead.

Comment: thank you @CD001, I added "name=submit" to my submit button, but all users are still registered as "M"

Comment: Well - the code you've shown here seems to be working as intended, if you submit the form you should see the correct radio button selected (e.g. if you check "Female" and view source you should see `<input type="radio" id="zip" name="zip" value="F" checked />`); if you're getting something else in the database, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: as far as I could tell from Chrome Dev Tools the value did not update to "checked" when selecting the radio button, I opened the ' <input type="radio" id="zip" name="zip" value="F" checked /> ' and tried selecting and un-selecting the checkbox but saw no change. 

I was unaware that this updated live in the view source

,If you would like to see the site it's ai.fossekalltek.no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is possibly in your petition.sign.js file.

I would try to replace this line:

```
$zip = $( 'input[name="zip"]', this ).val();
```

with this

```
$zip = $('input[name=zip]:checked').val();
```

Comment: Thank you @superhenke ! , I tried changing the line in the .js file but all users still register as male, even though I select "female" from the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by re-writing the PHP from scratch, how ever I do believe that my solution would not have worked without the input from @superhenke. I've attached the working PHP-code.

```
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $male_status = "unchecked";
            $female_status = "unchecked";
            $other_status = "unchecked";
            $selected_radio = $_POST["zip"];
            if ($selected_radio == "M") {

                $male_status = "checked";
            }
            elseif ($selected_radio == "F") {

                $female_status = "checked";

            }

            elseif ($selected_radio == "other") {

                $other_stauts = "checked";
            }
        }
        ?>

        <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'petition_zip' ) === true ) : ?>
            <p>Select your gender:</p>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="radio" id="male" name="zip" value="M" >
                    <label for="male">Male</label>

                    <input type="radio" id="female" name="zip" value="F">
                    <label for="female">Female</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="other" name="zip" value="O">
                    <label for="female">Other</label>
                </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
```